# How do I know whether an Event Handler has already been attached to a SharePoint O365 list?

Tags: custom-list, event-receivers, event-handlers, office-365

I have a SharePoint O365 site which has a custom list named **ReportMetadata**. There is an event receiver for this list for **ItemAdded** event which will take the image from the attachment column of the list, rename it as **ID.png** where ID is the in-built unique integral incremental column and paste it in the folder **MyImages** under **Style Library**. Now this functionality is working fine for my **TEST** and **PROD** environments but the image is not getting copied in the **DEV** environment. So I want to check whether the event receiver has been attached to the list in the DEV environment.
Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: Question elaborately explained.

Answer (score 0):

You can check with sharepoint online manager . You can try the free trial version to check the events.

https://store.office.com/sharepoint-manager-2013-online-WA104025157.aspx?queryid=6e5f213e-1ae8-4d5c-85f0-83712736e194&css=sharepoint%20manager&lc=en-us&assetid=WA104025157&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Otherwise you need to use client object model to check.

Comment: Our security setting does not allow the installation of the 3P app SharePoint Online Manager. Kindly guide me how to check this using CSOM.